# Refactoring a class that counts xml dom nodes and caches the result

Tags: php, object-oriented, xml, classes, curl

I saw this entertaining [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM&t=2965s) by: Bob Martin on clean code and started refactoring a relatively simple class today. I am, by no means, an expert on coding and still learning a lot every day, so I want to get this right eventually as well :).

The purpose of the code is to retrieve an xml document from a website, which contains open job vacancies, and simply counts the number of vacancies available. This number should be cached. Then either the cached value shall be returned or the xml shall be retrieved and parsed to extract the number job vacancies, which, in turn, should be put into the cache. The number is then used in another part of the app to show a "we're hiring" badge.

Would you be so kind and provide me with some feedback on:

- did I go too far with the extraction method here?
- did I not go far enough with the extraction method?
- can I refactor anything else?
- any other feedback on how to improve this code :)

Here is the before:

```
<?php

namespace mainBundle\Services;

use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

class JobCountProvider
{

    private $cache;
    public function __construct(CacheItemPoolInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function getJobCount()
    {
        $url = 'https://page-to-return-open-positions-xml.de/xml?language=de';

        $item = $this->cache->getItem('jobs-count');
        if ($item->isHit()) {
            $item->get();
            return $item->get();
        }

        try {
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
            $fileContents = str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\t"], '', $fileContents);
            $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
            $jobs = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 300);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            if (!$this->isValidXml($result)) {
                throw new \Exception('Error getting jobs xml');
            }

            $result = str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\t"], '', trim($result));
            $result = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $result));
            $jobs = simplexml_load_string($result);
            $count = $jobs->count();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->cache->save($item->set($count));
            $item->expiresAfter(432000);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $count = 0;
            $item->expiresAfter(0);
        }

        curl_close($ch);
        return $count;
    }

    private function isValidXml($content) {
        $content = trim($content);
        if (empty($content)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (stripos($content, '<!DOCTYPE html>') !== false) {
            return false;
        }

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        simplexml_load_string($content);
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        return empty($errors);
    }
}
```

And here is the after:

```
<?php

namespace mainBundle\Services;

use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

class JobCountProvider
{

    private $cache;
    public function __construct(CacheItemPoolInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function getJobCountFromPersonio(): int
    {
        $cachedJobCount = $this->isJobCountCached();
        if ($cachedJobCount !== null) {
            return $cachedJobCount;
        }

        $content = $this->getContentFromJobsPage(300);

        if (!$this->isValidXml($content)) {
            $this->cache->deleteItem('jobs-count');
            return 0;
        }

        $jobCount = $this->getSimpleXmlObjectFromString($content)->count();
        $this->saveJobCountToCache($jobCount);

        return $jobCount;
    }

    private function saveJobCountToCache(int $jobCount)
    {
        $item = $this->cache->getItem('jobs-count');
        $this->cache->save($item->set($jobCount));
        $item->expiresAfter(432000);
    }

    private function isJobCountCached()
    {
        $item = $this->cache->getItem('jobs-count');
        return  $item->isHit() ? $item->get() : null;
    }

    private function getSimpleXmlObjectFromString(string $string): \SimpleXMLElement
    {
        $string = str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\t"], '', trim($string));
        $xml = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $string));
        return simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }

    private function getContentFromJobsPage(int $conTimeoutInMs)
    {
        $urlToParse = 'https://page-to-return-open-positions-xml.de/xml?language=de';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlToParse);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, $conTimeoutInMs);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }

    private function isValidXml(string $xmlString)
    {
        $content = trim($xmlString);
        if (empty($content)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (stripos($content, '<!DOCTYPE html>') !== false) {
            return false;
        }

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        simplexml_load_string($content);
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        return empty($errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mast, I added a description on the purpose of the code and tried to improve the title.

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead, with links back and forth.

Comment: hm okey. I posted the code for others to benefit from, but if thats not allowed, ok :)

Comment: We understand the sentiment, we really do, but can you understand the mess it would create if people keep updating their question and more answers keep coming in? The first answer would no longer be applicable to the code presented. Possibly neither would the second.

Comment: Totally understand :)
May I post the new code as an "answer" to my own question?

Comment: If you post it as a review and not a code-dump, yes. If that review mentions points already in the other answers, that's fine, but all answers have to be reviews. If they happen to contain the final code as well, that's totally fine. Just, note the review part.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Mast what is the benefit of posting a new review that repeats advice already given?

Comment: I thought some might like to see the final code with all the changes we made together for completeness sake. It is not necessary, ppl can read the great suggestions by @mickmackusa and learn from those ☺️

Comment: @Sto I was just struck by "_If that review mentions points already in the other answers, that's fine_".  I was under the impression that Stack Exchange sites prefer not to waste researchers' time with redundant content.  I am not bothered if you post your final script.  I think it only needs to be the code, and then any **new** decisions you made and the logical reasons for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the `str_replace()` calls can be consolidated. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jBYaK))

  ```
  $string = "\ntext\r\ntab\t\ntext\"quote'\"text";
  var_dump(
      str_replace(
          ['"', "\r", "\n", "\t"],
          ["'", ''],
          $string
      )
  );
  ```
- I do like `return  $item->isHit() ? $item->get() : null;` which removes a redundant call.
- You might like to indicate the data type that a method returns.  E.g.:

  ```
  private function isValidXml(string $xmlString): bool
  ```
- Since your `trim()` call assumes that the incoming data `isset()`, then `empty()` is doing more "work" than necessary.  Perhaps this:

  ```
  $content = trim($xmlString);
  if (!$content || stripos($content, '<!DOCTYPE html>') !== false) {
      return false;
  }
  ```
- For DRYness, I would like to see `simplexml_load_string()` only called once in this class.  This would demand that the validation be integrated into the `getSimpleXmlObjectFromString()` method or that the xml is passed back it after the validating method was non-false.

Outside of these insights, your class seems pretty tidy to me.

---

After comments from the OP:

- I think I recommend the exception throwing technique from the original class. I am not overly confident on the best practices of writing awesome try-catch blocks, but it feels like the appropriate place for it. I don't follow why there are two catch blocks in the original class. ...Try not to get too concerned about method length -- the concern must be confined to ensuring that methods have a single responsibility.
- `getSimpleXmlObjectFromString()` is sanitizing and converting.  `isValidXml()` is validating before and after loading.  I think you need to decide how you want to remove the redundant loading.  Do you want separate methods that:

  1. `sanitizeString()`
  2. `validateString()`
  3. `validateXML()`

  Maybe, maybe not; but you should never ask php to perform the same operation on the same data more than once.
- Since `$errors = libxml_get_errors();` will ensure that the variable will be declared if reached, then `empty()` is doing unnecessary work. Like my earlier advice, just use a falsey check.

  ```
  return !$errors;
  ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my post. Very helpful comments, thank you. I have implemented your comments except the last :)

I am struggeling to find a good solution to only call `simplexml_load_string()` once in that class. Is it ok for the function `getSimpleXmlObjectFromString()` to either return a SimpleXml object or false? Then the function name is not suitable any more, but anything more added to it makes it too long I think.  

As is, it is quite readable I think. Making this change would make it somewhat less readable and easily understandable, no?

Comment: The other option to return the xml from the `isValidXml` means I need to change the function name as well, where I struggle. `returnSimpleXmlOrNull()` maybe to keep it as readable as possible?